# output char array in c++ produces wierd symbols

Tags: c++, string

I have this block of code to output a bunch of A's to a file (500 lines of 500 A's)

```
int main() {
    FILE * output = fopen("somefile.txt", "w");

    //initialize string
    char s[500];
    for(int i = 0;i < 500;i++) {
        //set each letter to 'A'
        s[i] = 'A';
    }
    for(int i = 0;i < 500;i++) {
        //output the string 500 times
        fprintf(output, "%s\n", s);
    }
}
```

However, there's a reverse '^' at the end of each line. ([screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Tfyt.png))

How do I get rid of it?

Comment: C strings (yes, this is C), need to be terminated with a nul character.

Comment: You should null terminate the string of As.  Use `char s[501] = {0};`

Comment: oh ty it worked :)

Comment: @user0042: as per the selected answer of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201101/how-to-initialize-all-members-of-an-array-to-the-same-value   the c-string should automatically get null terminated. But yes for greater specificity it should be `s[i]='\0';` after the `for` loop and array should be of size `501`.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @sameerkn Sorry, I were missing that you're proposing initialization like that. This would work, yes.

Answer (score 0):

The larger problem here is that you're not using the standard library, which would trivialise your problem. Here, you should be using `std::string`, then you don't need to worry about memory or null-terminators or anything else:

```
#include <string>
int main()
{
    std::string s(500, 'A');
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; ++i)
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

However, the reason you're experiencing what you are is because [`printf` requires a null-terminated string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf), so you'd need to write this instead:

```
char s[501] = {}; // default construct s so they're all null
for(int i = 0;i < 500;i++) {
    //set each letter to 'A'
    s[i] = 'A';
}
```